# How do I get inputRef to return <input> element from <Textfield>? Tried everything I can think of and it's still null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a TextField that I only render when another radiobutton is clicked. According to the React and Material-UI documentation, I should be able to get a ref to an input element inside a Mui TextField using inputRef={this.myRef} on the TextField. I'm able to do this for another TextField that is not toggled, but when I try that the with TextField that I just turn on, it shows null.

I've tried using inputRef={this.otherText} and inputProps={{ref: this.otherText}} and same result.

```
// Start of my class where I do the createRef()
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.otherText = React.createRef();
  }

// Start of function where I try to reference the ref:
processApplication = e => {
    if (e.target.value.toLowerCase() === 'other') { // this triggers the         TextField to be rendered
        console.log(this.otherText); // Returns null, kinda - see screenshot
    }

// The TextField I'm trying to reference:
<TextField
    id='applicationOther'
    name='applicationOther'
    label='Describe application:'
    margin='normal'
    multiline={true}
    fullWidth={true}
    onChange={this.anyChange}
    autoFocus={true}
    inputRef={this.otherText}  // Here's where the reference is made
/>
```

I expect this.otherText to have a reference to the  element, but this.otherText.current is null.

Comment: You say the TextField is only rendered under certain circumstances. That's very likely the reason why you're getting a null: It hasn't rendered yet. But in order to give you more details on why the timing isn't working we'll need to see your render method with its conditional render, your code for setting the state to hide/show, and your code for calling processApplication.

Comment: Can you explain what you want the `ref` for? 99% of the time you don't need them. they're good when you need to do width/height calculations

Comment: @NicholasTower yes that's what I'm thinking, I've moved on as this was not crucial and I was spending way too much. time. Thank you for the insight. I'm using it to set the text of an element once it appears.

Answer (score 1):

So to add some content to an input of any tipe, including Material `TextField`, you'd assign it as a `value`, for instance:

```
this.state = { input: 'Some string' }
<TextField value={this.state.input} />
```

Keep in mind the slight difference between uncontrolled and controlled components, so depending on your use case, you may want to pass `defaultValue` instead of `value`. From the docs:

> In the React rendering lifecycle, the value attribute on form elements will override the value in the DOM. With an uncontrolled component, you often want React to specify the initial value, but leave subsequent updates uncontrolled. To handle this case, you can specify a `defaultValue` attribute instead of `value`.

[Docs link](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Comment: I'm not using the ref to hide/show, I have that working based on a state variable like you're describing. What I'm trying to do with the ref is, once the object is visible, give it the right content.

Comment: So basically you're trying to render a `TextInput` with content that depends on the radio button? Something like, user clicks the button, some string gets stored in the state, that string gets fed to the input?

Comment: Yes, almost: 1. User clicks particular radio button, 2. text input shows up below radio buttons 3. Text input is prefilled with default text dependent on other state variables. My issue seems to be that the text input in not rendered when I try to access the ref to set the text.

Comment: Wouldn't you set the value to the `TextField` with something like `<TextField value={this.state.someKey} />`?

Comment: I was trying something like that before and wasn't able to get it to work, but now that I'm more familiar with React I think that is the solution. @predrag-beocanin if you want to update your answer to this I'll accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Usually this is the case! I've updated my answer, but please, if you run into any issues, just pop a quick codesandbox.io demo and get back to me, we'll sort it out in a jiffy

Answer (score 0):

I have had same issue, doing following worked for me:

```
<TextField
    variant="filled"
    inputRef={(input) => {
      if(input != null) {
         input.focus();
      }
    }}
/>
```

The trick here was `if(input != null)` in my case. You can also take a look at working example here: [CodeSandBox- Material-ui-TextFieldFocus](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-textfieldfocus-jz9gb?file=/src/App.tsx)